# Docker Enterprise daemon dies with "Windows named pipe error" during docker-compose up --build

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, windows-server-2016, docker-ee

I'm running Docker Enterprise on Windows Server 2016 (version 1607).  When I run `docker-compose up -d --build`, Docker begins building my project, but then fails after the first set of downloads is complete with this error:

```
Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-nanoserver-1803
2.1-sdk-nanoserver-1803: Pulling from microsoft/dotnet
e46172273a4e: Download complete
1f7d468f830c: Download complete
49e2df75adc8: Download complete
5bf149b5ccf5: Download complete
8b3ace20105f: Download complete
c17187292dad: Download complete
501949accc8a: Download complete
f87c5e7b5f65: Download complete
ERROR: Windows named pipe error: The pipe has been ended. (code: 109)
```

After this happens, all other `docker` commands fail as the daemon has stopped running.  I can verify this by taking a look in the Services window:

[image]

I have to manually restart the Docker service before I can execute any more `docker` commands.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Here's the output from `docker version`:

```
PS C:\> docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.10.0-ee-preview-3
 API version:  1.33
 Go version:   go1.8.4
 Git commit:   1649af8
 Built:        Fri Oct  6 17:52:28 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.10.0-ee-preview-3
 API version:  1.34 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.8.4
 Git commit:   b8571fd
 Built:        Fri Oct  6 18:01:48 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made two changes, and now I am no longer getting this error:

1. I realized I was using an experimental Docker version (`17.10.0-ee-preview-3`), so I rolled back to `17.06.2-ee-16`.
2. I learned the that version of Windows Server used by the host machine dictates which versions of Windows Server you can use inside a container.  See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility.  My containers now use a version of Windows Server that matches the version of my host.

I think point #1 above was the key.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error after rebooting windows. I wait a couple minuts and get the message that "docker-descktop is running". Now run the command and everythink works fine.